# How to delete single or selected offline post

Tags: java, android

I have a code to delete all the offline saved post at a time, I want to know if someone could help me with how to delete only selected post at a time.

Here is the code to delete all the post by one click.

```
private void deleteAllPosts() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    final RealmResults<RealmModel> results = realm.where(RealmModel.class).findAll();
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            results.deleteAllFromRealm();
                            posts.clear();
                            postAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, posts.size() - 1);
                            rvPostRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
                            rootView.findViewById(R.id.showLoading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    });

                    Snackbar.make(rvPostRecyclerView, "Successfully deleted all posts ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example, If you wants to delete post 1 and 2,

"post" is field name, "1" & "2" are values. you can have any number of values within the array.

```
final RealmResults<RealmModel> results = realm.where(RealmModel.class).in("post", ["1","2"]).findAll();
```

For more queries related things check [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html)